# PhoneGap - How to override back button whilst executing native code (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing a plugin on my PhoneGap Windows Phone 7 application. The plugin starts a thread on the Windows Phone 7 UI to launch the camera to scan QR codes. When it finishes executing, it returns to the PhoneGap UI.

The problem is that if the user presses the back button whilst the native plugin code is executing, the application crashes.

How do I override the back button for my PhoneGap plugin so that I can return to the PhoneGap UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a working solution to the problem, but it's not ideal.

When the back button is pressed whilst executing native plugin code, a navigation failed event is invoked in the App.xaml.cs file. It looks like this:

```
        // Code to execute if a navigation fails
    private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

I've simply replaced the above command with code which returns to the PhoneGap UI:

```
    private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).GoBack());
        }
    }
```

I think this will only work if you earlier created a new thread on the Windows Phone UI, which would look something like this:

```
var dispatcherOperation = Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => /* Your method */
```

The other thing to note is that the plugin code continues executing after pressed the back button. With my code, if the QR code scan didn't produce a result, it would attempt to go back to the PhoneGap UI, but this would fail since the back button event would have already returned to the PhoneGap UI, so I simply removed that statement from my plugin code.